# how to use transparent images to mask images and add an eventlistener

Tags: apache-flex

the easy part is to create the image and the mask for it:

```
// The jpg
var elementImage:Image = new Image();
elementImage.source = "/assets/materials/9/main-body.jpg";
elementImage.cacheAsBitmap = true;

// the mask
var elementImageMask:Image = new Image();
elementImageMask.source = "/assets/elements/4/main-body-mask.png";
elementImageMask.cacheAsBitmap = true;
elementImage.mask = elementImageMask;

addChild(elementImageMask);
addChild(elementImage);
```

my problem is that i want to add EventListener to the non transparent regions of the images.

```
elementImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
elementImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
```

but that's not working here. the event listener reacts even if i hover over the trasparent parts.

if i draw an vector graphic and use it to mask the image it works just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i monkeyed around with my code, and found sth:

instead of using a .png file as a mask you could also use a vector shape. you can also try using svg files (tinyurl.com/2xe9vs). it's working but:

> You cannot import SVG files at run time; you can only embed them in your Flex application at compile time.

**so the the solution is to use an .swf file:**

```
// The jpg
var elementImage:Image = new Image();
elementImage.source = "/assets/materials/9/main-body.jpg";

// the mask
var elementImageMask:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader();
elementImageMask.load("/flash/hoodie/body.swf");
elementImage.mask = elementImageMask;

addChild(elementImageMask);
addChild(elementImage);

elementImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
elementImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
```

you could also use the [InteractivePNG](http://blog.mosessupposes.com/?p=40) libary.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem: Solution is to set a sprite as a hitarea to the Object. Since I was to lazy to draw a hitarea-sprite myself, I wrote a simple method to convert a transparent png image to a sprite. [Detailed explanation how that works can be found here.](http://www.webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/creating-hitarea-png-image-transparent-alpha-regions-flex)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the  localX and localY of the MouseEvent are within the bounds of your mask. Otherwise, ignore the action.

Comment: If you know the size of the "elementImage" object, just make sure localX/localY are less than width/height. if(e.localX < elementImage.width && e.localY < elementImage.height) {...do stuff..}

Comment: ok that's right. but i have complex shapes in my png. yust using a square is not gonna help :(

Comment: Oops Sorry then. I'd have to monkey around with the code for a while to figure this out. I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.